# How to test the actual presence of platform i2c device in driver's probe() function

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, platform

I am writing an I2C bus driver. I have tested it on one external module I have plugged in my system (video card module) and it works. I have specified the i2c device (frequency, registers etc.) in device tree.

I would like to specify the rest of devices which will be using the driver in device tree as well. However, if I do that and the device is currently not present in the system, kernel fails to initialize. I guess this happens because in my probe function, I am setting up the frequency (which gets set up by writing to I2C register of that device - FPGA) and since the device isn't there - it just fails.

How should I solve this issue. Is there a way to check the actual physical presence in probe function without kernel failing? Or should I move the code that sets up frequency in another function that happens after ".master_xfer" when I'm reading/writing. The second option just seems like waste of resources. Another thing I had in mind was after I use open() to access the device in user-space, I should set the frequency in user-space as well. But I would really like all of this to happen inside the driver if possible. I'd like the frequency to be set after open() happens in userspace but for the code to execute in device driver code because there I access the register range specified in device tree. Maybe I could find where open() happens, check the ID of I2C device, than get the registers and do it there?

Comment: Can you provide a schema of your host / devices connection and relation with the mentioned driver(s)?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by placing the hardware init function (setting the frequency) into .master_xfer. So once the first message is received, frequency gets set and stays set for all the devices using the driver. I used a flag to save initialization status so it does not repeat uselessly..

Comment: It's obviously wrong location for a such. For the controller the proper initialization should be done in the certain functions (depends on hardware).